# Git authenticate error

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, windows-7, openssh

Created SSH-key with command:

```
ssh-keygen.exe -C "my@email.com" -t dsa
```

Entered passphrase, etc. Files were created: id_dsa, id_ds.pub in C:/Users/MyName/.ssh. File was added to git-auth: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Now trying to connect to git repo:
$ ssh -vT -p NNNN ssh://git@some-repo.com

Returns error:

```
$ ssh -vT -p 52967 ssh://git@some-repo.com.com
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to some-repo.com.com [216.70.245.85] port 52967.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.8 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to some-repo.com.com:52967 as 'ssh://git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:Zw5XXi0GgafMm6AhcKnNw+GzqkotZwXZYPWrZogG9KQ
debug1: Host '[some-repo.com.com]:52967' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa for not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ssh://git@some-repo.com.com's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh://git@some-repo.com.com's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh://git@some-repo.com.com's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

So it can't find the file `/c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa` but file exists, I see it in explorer or by ls command. What is the problem could be? What does this mean:

```
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa for not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
```

?

Actually with this command I'm trying to figure out authentication problem with Git 2.7.1 and TortoiseGit when I try to clone a repository. Cloning works fine with GitExtensions 2.48.05 with old MsysGit 1.9.5 (SSH 6.1), but fails with newest Git.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your private key to the ssh command you're doing:
`ssh -vT -p 52967 -i <path_to_your_private_key> ssh://git@some-repo.com.com`

Comment: This is not I'm looking for. Actually with this command I'm trying to figure out authentication problem with Git 2.7.1 and TortoiseGit when I try to clone a repository. Cloning works fine with GitExtensions 2.48.05 with old MsysGit 1.9.5 (SSH 6.1), but fails with newest Git.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ssh -vT -p 52967 ssh://git@some-repo.com.com
...
debug1: Authenticating to some-repo.com.com:52967 as 'ssh://git'
```

To start with, the OpenSSH `ssh` utility doesn't accept URLs on its command line. When it parses the string "ssh://git@some-repo.com.com" into a username and hostname, it's taking the entire string "ssh://git" as a username. You should remove the "ssh://" from the command which you are running:

```
ssh -vT -p 52967 git@some-repo.com.com
```

As for this error:

```
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa for not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
```

You are using SSH 7.1, which disables support for DSA type keys by default. You could use an RSA key instead, or see [this page](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) to reenable DSA key support in your client. In short, you'd add something like this to your local ssh config file:

```
Host some-repo.com.com
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: No above solution does not help. Actually with this command I'm trying to figure out authentication problem with Git 2.7.1 and TortoiseGit when I try to clone a repository. Cloning works fine with GitExtensions 2.48.05 with old MsysGit 1.9.5 (SSH 6.1), but fails with newest Git.